# How to add newlines/borders between errors and warnings in gcc/clang

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I understand that this may be a noob question, but often I have trouble figuring out where the error/warning starts when looking at build output, especially if it is from CI with CMake output sprinkled in or some remote machine(so no nice IDE highlighting).

Is there a way to tell gcc/clang to insert newlines or ------------ after and before every error warning?
This is especially imporant for deeply nested error(e.g. templates that die inside STL implementation).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Diagnostic-Message-Formatting-Options.html) docs, there are some formatting options that you can try, for example:

> -fdiagnostics-color=always

or by altering the minimum margin between errors:

> -fdiagnostics-minimum-margin-width=*width*

Refer to that page for an indepth explanations.